# Is it okay to say that degree of the given differential equation is 1?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y = 1 + \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} + \frac{1}{2!}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{3!}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^3 +\cdots+\frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^n.$$

I solved it using the exponential expansion for $\exp\left(\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)$. My question is if it is right to say that the degree of the differential equation is 1?

Comment: Degree of an equation is only defined for a polynomial equation. $e^\frac{dy}{dx}$  is not polynomial, its degree is undefined

Comment: @TheIntegrator Of course. I am an idiot.

Comment: And of course, the Taylor series for $e^z$ has infinitely many terms. Your series has only finitely many.

Comment: In answer to your question, your *order* is $1$ and your *degree* (as written) is $n$. But if you meant an infinite series that equalled $e^{y'}$, then your degree wouldn't be defined. But your order would remain $1$.